# Are the 240 roots of $E_8$ in ANY special relationship with any PARTICULAR set(s) of 1296 elements of $E_8$?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, root-systems

---

IMPORTANT: please do NOT read this post until you have read this metapost at this site here:

[An apology to this site (including a heart-felt "thank-you" note)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/an-apology-to-this-site-including-a-heart-felt-thank-you-note)

---

Are the 240 roots of $E_8$ in ANY special relationship with any PARTICULAR set(s) of 1296 elements of $E_8$?

If the answer to this question is "yes", then I can probably go away and stop bothering you good people, at least for a few weeks.

Because if the answer is "yes", then the answer will probably tell me exactly how $E_8$ is instantiated in the energetics of the particular biomolecular subsystem which my team has been studying for quite a number of years.

So, if you'd like me to go away, at least for a while, please take a moment to think about this question.  And thanks as always for whatever time you can afford to spend doing so.

Comment: I don't see anything right away. The next shell on the $E_8$-lattice has [2160 vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice#Theta_function). I just counted them myself to make sure they didn't miss any! I don't see this number in the theta series of E6 [either](http://oeis.org/A004007). I'm afraid I don't really know the polytope stuff. I was rather expecting that you describe the set of vectors (or molecules even!) that you think have some large Weyl group (or a subgroup) as its group of symmetries.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - thank you so much!!!! - believe it or not, I know exactly what your 2160 "means" in terms of the model we're developing!!!! But I wouldn't have known this until last night because it wasn't until last night that I realized how to reconcile a critical (144,96) split of 240 in our model with the standard split of (128,112) given by the usual coordinatization of $E_8$.  And the number 2160 is implied by the nature of that reconciliation in several different ways.  I will post back on this when I have more details , but I think you've put me on the right track  - THANK YOU!!!!!!